# "How soon will we be moving along?" help me to understand the grammar

Tags: tense, idioms, questions

> How soon will we **be** **moving** along?

Move along *(idiom)*: continue to move; to start moving out of the way.

Why do we use "be + <verb>ing" in this question? Can we modify verbs in idioms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that it's talking about the future, i.e how soon do you think it will happen! The statement resembles to Future Continuous Tense. be+ing.
Changing verbs in your sentence will make you to add some additional supporting words to it.

I hope this helped,although I am practising grammar and is just in school.

Comment: yeah, you right. Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: but Is there any meaning change if I use the future tense?

Comment: It depends on how you construct your sentence. There are hundreds of ways to construct a sentence it may be right it may be wrong. You just need to be sure you go right. Even I'm learning.Nothing's bad in being wrong.